# Spring-Social facebook using PagingParameters and page count

Tags: facebook, spring, facebook-graph-api, spring-social

I'm using spring-social for facebook, `<version>2.0.0.RC1</version>`
I have some problem using PagingParameters, I want to read all feed using pages.

this is the code:

```
PagedList<Post> page1;
    try {
        page1 = facebook.feedOperations().getFeed(new PagingParameters(50,0,null,null ));
        logger.info("* * * * * * * * * * * * * Page_size: " + page1.size());
        while (page1.size() > 0) {
           ...
            PagingParameters p =  page1.getNextPage();// 
            page1 = facebook.feedOperations().getFeed(p);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

In this version seems work correctly (since the current stable version it dosen't work corretly).

Well, if I want to start read feed using form a date I have always a `page.size()`= 0;

I'm using "since" date as:

```
page1 = facebook.feedOperations().getFeed(new PagingParameters(50,0,myJavaDateTime.getTime(),new Date().getTime()));
```

I didn't find the way to set the date. 
How can I use the "since" date?

Thank you, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem:
The facebook API needs the seconds but the java  `getTime` gets milliseconds.

I just divided by 1000 and it works correctly now.

```
 page1 = facebook.feedOperations().getFeed(new
 PagingParameters(50,0,myJavaDateTime.getTime()/1000 <--- added this
```